# HDInsight hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar where is the Output?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, azure-hdinsight

I ran the sample wordcount application in HDInsight The command ran successfully, but I cannot find the output. 
The command that I ran 
is

```
hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar wordcount /example/data/gutenberg/davinci.txt /user/joe/WordCountOutput
```

I am expecting something to be created on the file system . But I don't see `/user/joe/` created.

Please advice.

Comment: I got confused with the file structure that I saw in the Name Node. It had a very similar file structure to the Azure Blob Storage. The output was actually created on the Azure Blob Storage and I kept looking in the Name Node's  file system from where I ran the command.

Comment: So if the problem is solved, mark an answer as accepted, or write and accept a new one of your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDInsight uses Azure blob storage as its HDFS store by default therefore your output is in your storage account associated with the cluster. You can use something like [CloudXplorer](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer) to easily read your blob storage account and find this data. It will be in your default WABS container under  /user/joe/WordCountOutput

You could also run your command like this to have more control over your output location

```
hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar wordcount /example/data/gutenberg/davinci.txt wabs://<contatiner>@<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/user/joe/WordCountOutput
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not in your machine's filesystem, but on [Azure blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure-storage-blobs/info). Typically, Hadoop MapReduce uses the [Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hdfs/info), but as Thomas Jungblut correctly pointed in his comment, Azure blobs has completely replaced HDFS in HDInsight. Still, you should be able to access the output using the [hdfs shell commands](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html), like:

```
hadoop dfs -ls /user/jow/WordCountOutput
```

Perhaps HDInsight offers more ways to browse this filesystem (see [Andrew Moll's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35561079/2516301)), but I am not familiar with them, and this is actually quite easy already.

Comment: HDInsight replaces HDFS completely with Azure blobs, so it is not on HDFS. However, since `hadoop dfs` accesses it through the same filesystem interface, he would see the data through the command.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasJungblut for your constructive comment. I will update my answer accordingly.